# Let $V$ be the space of complex polynomials on $[0,1]$. Is the differentiation operator self-adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is the space of all complex polynomials of degree $N$ or less restricted to $[0,1]$. Equipped with the inherited inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt$.

So for the setup above, let $D$ be the differentiation operator so
$$
D(a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_N t^N) = a_1 + 2 a_2 t + \cdots + N a_N t^{N-1}
$$
Is $D$ is self adjoint or skew adjoint?

**Attempt/Thoughts**

In thinking about it, I know I can write the inner product as
$$
\int_0^1 f \overline g dt = \sum_{i,j=0}^N \frac{a_i \overline b_j}{i+j+1}
$$
with $a_k$ and $b_k$ as the coefficients of polynomials $f$ and $g$, respectively. Then
$$
\langle Df, g \rangle = \sum_{i=1,j=0}^N \frac{i a_i \overline b_j}{i+j}
$$
and
$$
\langle f, Dg \rangle = \sum_{i=0,j=1}^N \frac{j a_i \overline b_j}{i+j}
$$
so it would seem that $D$ is neither self adjoint or skew adjoint. Is this the right way to approach my question?

Another thought I had was integration by parts, but that didn't seem produce anything useful when I tried it.

Comment: Well I guess $\langle Dx, x^2\rangle \neq \langle x, Dx^2 \rangle$. I think integration by parts will give you a boundary condition you need for $D$ to be symmetric.

Comment: Integration by parts gives me $\langle Df, g \rangle = \sum\sum a_i \overline b_j - a_0 \overline b_0 - \int_0^1 f \frac{\partial \overline g}{\partial t} dt$. Does that give us something useful?

Comment: well the second term is $\langle f, Dg \rangle$ and the first term should only depend on the values of $f,g$ at the boundary, so you can impose conditions to force it to be $0$. If I didn't mess up the sign, I think if you take $D=i\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ as your differential operator(which is the usual convention), you should get a  symmetric operator

Comment: @Qidi, I have revised my question to clearly define $D$. I don't think this aligns with your suggestion, does it? Where can I find that definition of the differential operator, which you say is the usual convention?

Comment: As I mentioned $\langle Dx, x^2 \rangle$ and $\langle x, Dx^2 \rangle$ tells you $D$ is neither self-adjoint nor skew-adjoint. You could impose boundary conditions e.g. polynomials that vanish at the boundary, then $D$ will be skew-adjoint. If you add an $i$ in front of $D$ it will be self-adjoint. I think "usual" is a very subjective word, so I probably shouldn't have said it. Anyways in a lot of situations I have encountered having an $i$ makes life easier. For example if you check the wikipedia entry of differential operator it is mentioned.

Comment: As an additional remark, it is important here that $V$ is finite dimensional, or else $D$ would be unbounded, and self-adjoint might make no sense. One would then discuss the extension of $D$ here instead of $D$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already established in comments, $D$ is neither self-adjoint nor skew adjoint. In my opinion, the reason for this behaviour lies in the fact that $D$ lowers the degree of the polynomial it is applied to.

Consider an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of polynomials of increasing degree: 
$$
\mathcal B = (P_0, P_1, \ldots, P_N).$$
By this I mean that the degree of $P_j$ is $j$ and
$$\int_0^1P_jP_k\,dx = \delta_{jk}.$$Such a basis is obtained by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the usual basis $(1, x, x^2,\ldots x^N)$ (in the language of special functions, those are the normalized *shifted Legendre polynomials*).

The operator $D$ is self adjoint (or skew adjoint) if and only if its associated matrix with respect to $\mathcal B$ is symmetric (or skew symmetric). Since 
$$
DP_0=0,\quad DP_k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_{kj}P_j, $$
this matrix has the form 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & * & * & \ldots & * \\ 
0 & 0 & * & \ldots & * \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & * \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & * \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and clearly it has neither of the required symmetry properties.

Comment: What if we add (for example) the conditions $P(0)=0=P(1)$? Then the operator becomes symmetric, despite the degree-lowering aspect. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: :-) Ok, let me lay all my cards on the table. My idea is that $D$ is not symmetric because it is nilpotent: $D^{N+1}=0$. According to my intuition, a nilpotent symmetric operator is trivial, and that's what I tried to convey in this answer. But I don't know how to reconcile this intuition with your observation.

Comment: :) Indeed, the restriction to the subspace meeting the vanishing-at-endpoints condition is no longer nilpotent! :)  Also, one has to stop and think about how to interpret the point that second derivative does not preserve the vanishing-at-endpoint condition. :) I guess the point is that seemingly small changes can have larger consequences than we'd naively imagine. Pretty funny stuff...